# Connect to a on-premise MySQL server from Google Cloud Run

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-run

Is it possible to connect to a On-Premise MySQL server from Google Cloud Run? I saw that you can connect to their own Cloud SQL service, but we want to use our own server.

Comment: Do you allow connections from any IP to your on prem MySQL server?

Comment: if needed we can take that risk.

Comment: In that case I don't see it being an issue, have you ran into any roadblocks so far?

Comment: I actually didn't try it yet. I only used Cloud Run with Could Sql. Thanks for your insight. Is it possible to know a the ip with Cloud Run will use?

Comment: Yeah that was the issue I was envisioning. I don't believe that it's possible to know the outgoing IP for Cloud Run, so unless you use Cloud SQL or allow all external IPs from your on prem DB then you'll likely run into issues.

Comment: You can also create a VPN between your VPC and your on prem network where is hosted your MySQL server. And then use the mysql server private IP